# How do I format a double value in XAML to German format?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, format, double

I have this simple piece of code and I am wondering how to convert it to German format (#.###,##) ?

```
// displays #.##
<Label Content="{Binding MySumValue}"/>
```

Comment: If you want to convert the bound value you'll have to look into the IValueConverter interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set the [`ContentStringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Label` or just StringFormat for `TextBlock` with necessary [`xml:lang`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/04/25/introducing-xml-lang-in-xaml.aspx).

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="MyButton" 
            Content="OK" 
            Width="100,999" 
            Height="25" />

    <Label Name="MyLabel"                
           Content="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=MyButton}"
           xml:lang="de-DE"
           ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N2}" /> 
</Grid>
```

`Output`

[image]

Comment: I opened a new question for DataGridTextColumn here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325627/how-do-i-format-a-double-value-in-xaml-to-german-format-on-a-datagridtextcolumn