# How do I format a double value in XAML to German format on a DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, format, double

I have this simple piece of code and I am wondering how to convert it to German format (#.###,##) ?

```
// displays #.##
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Sum Value" Binding="{Binding SumValue}"/>
```

Comment: @Soner Gönül: What makes you think that it is a duplicate? The first question about display value in `Label`, here refers to the `DataGrid` - are two different topics. More globally: or the question: how to program in Pascal and how to program in C++ - one the same question?

Comment: It is no duplicate. It was told to me by Anatoliy Nikolaev that I have to open a new question for this.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev You are right. Retracted my vote.

Answer (score 0):

In this case try several options:

> A. Global setting language culture for the entire application, it can solve some problems related to the current language culture.

Add `Startup` event for `App.xaml`, which establishes the necessary language culture. It affects the display of the date, double values​​, sums of money, etc:

`XAML`

```
<Application x:Class="DataGridTargetUpdateHelp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">

    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("de-DE"))); // CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag return the current code of language
    }
}
```

> B. Use the `DataGridTemplateColumn`

In this case you can set any `Control` to display values in the DataGridCell:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" xml:lang="de-DE" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: If I use solution A) my data grid values get partially more than two decimal places. How do I limit the decimal places to two places here?

Comment: @user3524628: Perhaps you need to use `StringFormat`. Can you show an example of the output?